# cypress conditional testing with labels/text

Tags: conditional-statements, cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

How do you do conditional testing in cypress with labels?
For example: I want to know if there is the "ole" written in between the span:

```
<div>
  <span role="test">ole</span> 
</div>
```

Now with the attribute this is well documented and works nicely:

```
cy.get('div').then((ol) => {
   if(ol.find('span[role="test"]').length){
       // do something
   } else {
       // do something else
   }
})
```

But with labels??

```
cy.get('div').then((ol) => {
   if(ol.contains('ole').length){  // this does not work!
       // do something
   } else {
       // do something else
   }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent for text in the element is `.text()`.

Technically it's only a label if it's labeling something, but `.text()` applies to anything between the opening and closing tags.

```js
cy.get('div').then((ol) => {
  if (ol.text() === 'ole') {  
  
  } else {
  
  }
})
```

Comment: Actually it could work. I unfortunately I used:   cy.get('div).within((ol) => {
      if (ol.text('ole').length) {    this actually modifies the page and replaces the tag with 'ole'. <br> According to documentation: text() = "Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text."

Comment: That's a mistake - I should have given you a link to the docs - `.text()` does not take any parameters.

Comment: And you don't use `.text().length` - it returns a string not a jQuery object. (hence `ol.text() === 'ole'`)

Comment: Yes. Thanks I see that now :-)